# Aplicar CSS a array de objetos en JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito que este array de objetos en JSON

```
<script> var galeriaOriginal={"frases":[{"persona":"Bender Bending Rodríguez","frase":"Los robots no tenemos sentimientos... y eso me pone tan triste...","foto":"http://www.topimagenes.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/bender-futurama-7-desconfiado.jpg"},{"persona":"Pikachu","frase":"Pika Pika ","foto":"http://st-listas.20minutos.es/images/2011-11/310549/3269993_249px.jpg?1325815180"},{"persona":"Tyrion Lannister","frase":"Cuando doy el dinero para un regalo conjunto digo: Un Lannister siempre paga sus deudas.","foto":"http://i24web.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/tyrion-lannister-wallpaper-pack-01-700x525.png"}]}</script>
```

Se me muestre de esta forma en un archivo JS por medio de CSS y se guarde como localstorage

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no se como hacerlo, he llegado a hacer esto:

```
function mostrarFrases(){

//Cargamos la galeria para mostrarla
galeria=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("frases"));

for (var cont=0;cont<galeria.frases.length;cont++)
{

    document.write(galeria.frases[cont].frase);
    document.write(galeria.frases[cont].persona);
    document.write(galeria.frases[cont].foto);
}
```

}

Pero esto me muestra todo el texto sin formato y en vez de las imagenes me aparece la ruta solamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy novato, haber si alguno me puede ayudar :D

Comment: Bienvenido para que tengas una excelente respuesta te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: Una pregunta, estás usando jQuery o solo javaScript nativo?

Comment: Solo nativo, jquery nunca lo he utilizado

Comment: Puede hacer esto para que dibuje tu imagen

var elem = document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="'+galeria.frases[cont].foto+'">';
document.body.appendChild(elem);

Esto inserta html en la pagina, y le dices q va a ser una img

Comment: Lo he probado, pero solo me sale la primera foto, y necesito que me aparezcan las 3, aparte de que solo me valdria para la imagen y tengo que cambiar el texto tambien

Comment: No entiendo algo, que es lo que quieres que se guarde en el localstorage????

Comment: EL JSON que puse arriba, pero eso si que lo hice, lo que no consigo es aplicar el css al array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que se vea como tu quieres debes crear una estructura **HTML** y asignarle estilos **CSS** a la misma, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

**Manera larga:**

```js
var contenedor = document.querySelector('.contenedor');

var galeriaOriginal = {
  "frases":[{
    "persona":"Bender Bending Rodríguez",
    "frase":"Los robots no tenemos sentimientos... y eso me pone tan triste...",
    "foto":"http://www.topimagenes.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/bender-futurama-7-desconfiado.jpg"
  }, {
    "persona":"Pikachu",
    "frase":"Pika Pika ",
    "foto":"http://st-listas.20minutos.es/images/2011-11/310549/3269993_249px.jpg?1325815180"
  }, {
    "persona":"Tyrion Lannister",
    "frase":"Cuando doy el dinero para un regalo conjunto digo: Un Lannister siempre paga sus deudas.",
    "foto":"http://i24web.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/tyrion-lannister-wallpaper-pack-01-700x525.png"
  }]
}

function mostrarFrases(){
  //Cargamos la galeria para mostrarla
  galeriaOriginal.frases.forEach(function(dato){
    var personaje = document.createElement('div');
    personaje.setAttribute('class', 'personaje');

    var texto = document.createElement('div');
    texto.setAttribute('class', 'texto');

    var titulo = document.createElement('h1');
    titulo.innerHTML = dato.frase;
    texto.appendChild(titulo);

    var frase = document.createElement('p');
    frase.innerHTML = dato.persona;
    texto.appendChild(frase);

    personaje.appendChild(texto);

    var foto = document.createElement('img');
    foto.src = dato.foto;
    personaje.appendChild(foto);

    contenedor.appendChild(personaje);
  });        
}

mostrarFrases();
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.personaje{
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

.personaje .texto h1{
  color: white;
  max-width: 60%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.personaje .texto p{
  color: white;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.personaje img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor"></div>
```

**Manera corta:**

```js
var contenedor = document.querySelector('.contenedor');

var galeriaOriginal = {
  "frases":[{
    "persona":"Bender Bending Rodríguez",
    "frase":"Los robots no tenemos sentimientos... y eso me pone tan triste...",
    "foto":"http://www.topimagenes.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/bender-futurama-7-desconfiado.jpg"
  }, {
    "persona":"Pikachu",
    "frase":"Pika Pika ",
    "foto":"http://st-listas.20minutos.es/images/2011-11/310549/3269993_249px.jpg?1325815180"
  }, {
    "persona":"Tyrion Lannister",
    "frase":"Cuando doy el dinero para un regalo conjunto digo: Un Lannister siempre paga sus deudas.",
    "foto":"http://i24web.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/tyrion-lannister-wallpaper-pack-01-700x525.png"
  }]
}

function mostrarFrases(){
  galeriaOriginal.frases.forEach(function(dato){
    contenedor.innerHTML += '<div class="personaje"><div class="texto"><h1>'+ dato.frase +'</h1><p>'+ dato.persona +'</p></div><img src="'+ dato.foto +'"></div>';
  });        
}

mostrarFrases();
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.personaje{
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

.personaje .texto h1{
  color: white;
  max-width: 60%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.personaje .texto p{
  color: white;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.personaje img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor"></div>
```

Comment: WOW muchas gracias, justo lo que quería

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa si no te importa perder la compatibilidad con Internet Explorer es usar un elemento `template` y generar los elementos a partir de la plantilla:

```js
var galeria={"frases":[{"persona":"Bender Bending Rodríguez","frase":"Los robots no tenemos sentimientos... y eso me pone tan triste...","foto":"http://www.topimagenes.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/bender-futurama-7-desconfiado.jpg"},{"persona":"Pikachu","frase":"Pika Pika ","foto":"http://st-listas.20minutos.es/images/2011-11/310549/3269993_249px.jpg?1325815180"},{"persona":"Tyrion Lannister","frase":"Cuando doy el dinero para un regalo conjunto digo: Un Lannister siempre paga sus deudas.","foto":"http://i24web.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/tyrion-lannister-wallpaper-pack-01-700x525.png"}]}

function mostrarFrases(){
  // referencias a la plantilla y sus elementos
  var template = document.getElementById('card');
  var frase = template.content.querySelector('.frase');
  var autor = template.content.querySelector('.autor');
  var imagen = template.content.querySelector('img');

  for (var cont=0;cont<galeria.frases.length;cont++)
  {
    // Asigna los valores
    frase.textContent = galeria.frases[cont].frase;
    autor.textContent = galeria.frases[cont].persona;
    imagen.src = galeria.frases[cont].foto;
    // Crea un nuevo elemento a partir de la plantilla
    var newcard = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    // Añade el nuevo elemento
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(newcard);
  }        
}

mostrarFrases();
```

```css
.contenedor{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.texto{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.texto span{
  display: block;
}
.autor{
  font-style: italic;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.borrar{
  text-align: center;
}
.contenedor img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<template id="card">
  <article class="contenedor">
    <div class="texto">
      <span class="frase"></span>
      <span class="autor"></span>
      <div class="borrar">
        <button>Borrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img />
  </article>
</template>
```

Comment: El de arriba me sirvió pero muchas gracias a ti también por tomarte tu tiempo :)